# remove white background with ImageMagick but not the white inside picture?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

im trying to delete the background with a batch process in pictures of products for an e-commerce site.

The problem is that the script also remove the white color in the inside of the product, leaving the product transparent in some areas..

For example:

[image]

Command:

```
convert *.jpg  -set filename: %t -fuzz 5% -transparent white %[filename:].png
```

this is the best I can get..im ok with this result around the product, but I need that the white inside the product remains white and not transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that it doesn't respect boundaries, it is just applied globally, making all white pixels transparent regardless of their connectivity to the background.

Instead, you will get on better using a *"floodfill"* that only floods into areas that are within the fuzz distance of the top-left corner pixel.

So, I chose an unused colour of magenta so you can see what is happening:

```
convert product.jpg -fuzz 5% -fill magenta -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' result.png
```

[image]

You would then follow that with the command to make magenta transparent like this:

```
convert product.jpg -fuzz 5% -fill magenta -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' -transparent magenta result.png
```

[image]

Comment: works great, but I have some products that the left side does not connect with the right side..so it remains white... how can I do it also top-right corner? I try modify the 0,0 to 200,200 or 200,0 but doesnt work

Comment: @JonTargaryen You can add a border around the image for the flood fill to flow all the way around. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39929189/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36983738/2836621