# Replacing white background with transparency with iMageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57146467/remove-white-background-with-imagemagick-but-not-the-white-inside-picture) already given to same question: `-fuzz 5% -fill magenta -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' -transparent magenta result.png`but I must have failed it when I converted it to my workflow as it removes all white within the drawing as well. `cd`
`cd desktop/drawings`
`magick mogrify -path ../drawings2 -format png -fuzz 40% -fill white -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' -transparent white *.png`

Here's a before/after with before a jpeg for size requirement.

[[image: OriginalMandala]] [[image: ConvertedMandala]]

Comment: Images look the same here but on computer the second is transparent where not black.

Comment: JPG does not support transparency. You need to save as PNG. To make the first transparent use something like `convert image.jpg -fuzz 15% -transparent white image.png`. Increase the fuzz value if it is not all transparent.

Comment: Thak you. Could you possibly change your code to match the way I have it setup with folders? Embarrassed to ask my brain just can't grasp coding.  I'm using PNG with ImageMaagick, not JPG at all. It was a quick solution to my PNG being rejected for being too large.

Comment: `cd cd desktop/drawings magick mogrify -path ../drawings2 -format png -fuzz 15% -transparent white *.png` Increase fuzz value as needed.

Comment: It's still removing all white including within the drawings but the backgrounds look lovely.

Comment: So what do you want?  Do you want the inside of the black lines to be white and outside to be transparent? If so, `cd cd desktop/drawings magick mogrify -path ../drawings2 -format png -fuzz 15% -fill none -draw "alpha 0,0 floodfill" *.png`